# Is it possible to persist Drive Picker widget settings across pages?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have 2 pages in my app.  Page 1 allows the user to select a pupil and then the app shows Page 2.

On Page 2 I have a Drive Picker widget that allows the user to choose images that will be copied to a specific folder (depends on what was selected on Page 1).
If the user closes the picker on Page 2 after picking files and then opens it again without visiting Page 1 first, the Drive Picker remembers which specific folder they had navigated to and allows them to continue.

If the user visits Page 1 again first to select a different pupil and then comes back to Page 2 and uses the Picker, it seems as if the Picker gets reset and shows the user the root of their Drive again.  I want to avoid this behaviour so that the user can continue to select files from their last visit (in the same session) to Page 2.

Is there anyway to access the last visited folder of the picker and store that say in a page property and then make the picker use that property the next time it is opened?

I have become a little confused as well with the options that are available to the widget and the options that are surfaced through the result object.  I confess that I've tried to search stack overflow for more information on how to use result object, but cannot surface much so all of my scripts use the widget.selectedDocuments way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage() to keep variables between pages.
It is a client side function and does not support "custom action" as far as i know, but the following functions can fix that.

```
function get_ss(name){return sessionStoreage.getItem(name);}
function set_ss(name, val){sessionStorage.setItem(name, val);}
```

when navigating from page 1 you can use a custom action to get pupil and set it in sessionStorage then navigate to page2

```
"Custom Action=" set_ss("pupil", app.pages.Page1.decendents.PupilName.value); app.showPage(app.pages.Page2); //going from memory on the navigation code
```

You can add "var pupil = get_ss("pupil");" where ever you need it from there.

Comment: Hi Scott and thanks for the info on session variables.  They sound like they could be more useful than App Maker's built in Page.Properties system which I am already using to persist the selected Pupil between pages.

Comment: However, my question is more geared towards being able to find out from the Drive Picker widget what the last selected folder was so that when I initialise the picker again I can pass this in and the picker will continue from where it left off.  Once I can get that information I can store it as you suggested and go from there.

Comment: you can get the selected file's parent and then uses that initialize the view to the parent view in the next page. there is a q/a on this stackoverflow on how to do that for drive picker...